# Ruby on Rails : What do I do to get Access Tokens via fb_graph2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fb-graph

```
> auth = FbGraph2::Auth.new(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
> auth.debug_token! 'obtained-access-token'
```

I'v tried the code above, and the `auth.debug_token` is `NULL`.

I want to create a page and it will appear pop-up that wants users to authorize itself to post message on users' `Facebook`. And then I can post random strings to specified user. However I can only post message on my own Facebook because I can only get my `Access Tokens`. Now, I have app id and app secrete number and installed `fb_graph2 gem`. What next?